# Can you apply a lifecycle policy to every item in a GCS Bucket that DOES NOT match a prefix?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I know that GCS supports conditional lifecycle policies. One of the conditions is `matchesPrefix`.

However, I need to do the opposite. I have a bucket that gets a lot of unnecessary metadata, but one folder has significant data which cannot be deleted.
So I want to apply my policy to delete every object every 30 days, except the important folder. But I don't see a way to tell GCS to delete everything that is not matching my `Foo/Bar` prefix.

The prefixes of the rest of the files is random, so adding a condition to affect only them is not possible.

Comment: I suspect that you'll have to end up creating a separate bucket for the special data, and configure it differently.

Comment: AFAIK cannot do this as these files are being generated by dataflow and there's only one place to indicate where to put them. I don't get to pick which files are generated

Comment: Then you might have to build something to post-process the uploads in the way you require.